# How to disable wordpress Visual and HTML editor?

Tags: wordpress, text-editor

Is it possible to remove both the Visual and HTML editor for the wordpress users? I am aware of the option to disable the visual editor, but I'd like to disable the HTML editor as well and will like to have a plain text area.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be changed for Post or Page content types without hacking the core (which one should never do).

You can create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) that does not support 'editor', but does support 'excerpt' (which accepts plain text). See the 'supports' paramater of the [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function.